# Combo box in entity edmx

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

I'm newbie to c#.  I have a question about combobox binding with foreign key in entity edmx object.

I have "Customer Card" edmx entity object that has fields and one of the fields is foreign key (CityID) of this customer that contains an ID to the list of Cities table or "City" entity object.

I want to manage the customer City combobox in my code. I'm populating the combobox. Also retrieving the current selected item when the user save the record. However; i'm not sure how to assign the selected item in the combo item back to the Customer entity object. All I see in the entity object is City and CityReference property. My question is how do I assign the current city ID selected item to the "customer card" in the entity object? Please include the code.

Here is my code

```
    private class CustCard
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    public class CityCard
    {
       public int ID {get; set;}
       public string Name {get; set;}
       public string Country {get; set;}
    }

    var custCards = from p in entities.CustomerCards
                        select new CustCard
                        {
                            ID = p.ID,
                            CompanyName = p.CompanyName,
                            ContactName = p.ContactName,
                            City = p.City.Name,
                            CityID = p.City.ID,
                        };

    var cityList = from p in entities.Cities
                       select new CityCard
                       {
                            ID = p.ID,
                            Name = p.Name,
                            Country = p.Country.Name,
                       };

    //Bind City List
    CityComboBox.DataSource = CityList; //cities in the entity object
    CityComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
    CityComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            CustomerCard Cust = new CustomerCard();

            Cust.Address = addressTextBox.Text;
            Cust.CompanyName = companyNameTextBox.Text;


            **// HOW CAN I assign Selected item to the City field in the CustCard
            ????????????cityIDComboBox.SelectedItem;?????????????**

            entities.AddToCustomerCards(Cust);
            entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

how about...

```
Cust.City = CityComboBox.SelectedItem.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            CustomerCard Cust = new CustomerCard();

            Cust.Address = addressTextBox.Text;
            Cust.CompanyName = companyNameTextBox.Text;


            Cust.City = CityComboBox.SelectedItem.Name;
            Cust.CityID = CityComboBox.SelectedItem.Value;

            entities.AddToCustomerCards(Cust);
            entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: do you mean p.City.ID = ((CityCard)cityIDComboBox.SelectedItem).ID;

Comment: When I do this I get an exception:An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Accounting2.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Did you select something first?  If nothign is selected, CityComboBox.SelectedItem will be null.    Also make sure that entities has been initialized

Comment: It seems that the code is creating new entry in the City table. It is calling insert when I call AddToCustomerCards! I just want to use an existing CityID entry. Do you know the problem?